# Can ABNewPersonViewController be used to edit existing records?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, addressbookui

I'm trying to use `ABNewPersonViewController` to edit an existing record.
I set the `displayedPerson` property and it shows up fine with all the info.
If I hit `Save`, everything works as expected. However, if I hit `Cancel`, the record is **deleted from the Address Book**.

The only solution I can think it is deep copying the record and then re-adding it to the Address Book if the user cancels out of the editing dialog. Is there really no better way?

Comment: Just curious, why don't you use "ABPersonViewController"?

Comment: Because I need a heavily customized version of it, so I've rolled out my own.

Answer (score 2):

add a custom "Cancel" button to replace the original "cancel" button of ABNewPersonViewController!!