# Can ABNewPersonViewController be used to edit existing records?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can ABNewPersonViewController be used to edit existing records?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840394/can-abnewpersonviewcontroller-be-used-to-edit-existing-records)

I'm trying to using ABNewPersonViewController to edit an existing record. I set the displayedPerson property and it shows up fine with all the info. If I hit 'Save', everything works as expected. However, if I hit 'Cancel', the record is deleted from the Address Book.

I can't use ABPersonViewController since I have a customized contact info page and need to open the editing page through my page. If you confirm that it is nonpossible to do like this, can you give me some other solutions.

The only solution I can think if is deep copying the record and then re-adding it to the Address Book if the user cancels out of the editing dialog. Is there really no better way?

Answer (score 0):

Go through  [QuickContact](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/QuickContacts/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009475) Sample Project