# ABNewPersonViewController deletes contact on cancel

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am using an `ABNewPersonViewController` to create a person. Everything works fine so far. I do set  multivalue properties as well as single values. After tapping "Add" the contact can be found in the adressbook.

But there is a problem when editing this contact. After adding the contact to the adressbook, I save the `addressbookID`, so that I am able to identfiy if the contact is still saved in the AB.

So If the user wants to export a contact again, I do not create a new `ABPersonRecordRef`, but using the existing one identified by the id I have saved before:

```
    ABRecordID recordId = [aContact.addressBookRecordId intValue];

    ABRecordRef personRecord = nil;
    if(recordId != 0) {
        personRecord = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(addressBook, recordId);
        if(personRecord) {
            return personRecord;
        } else {
            personRecord = ABPersonCreate();
        }
    } else {
        personRecord = ABPersonCreate();
    }
    //set properties etc.
```

The problem now is, that this just works the first time. If the user displays the person a second time in the `ABNewPersonViewController` and taps on Cancel, the record will be deleted in the adress book. Although it was previously saved fine.

I tried using an `ABUnknownPersonViewController`, but the problem is that it seems that the attributes det on the recordRef are not displayed exactly like in the `ABNewPersonViewController`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be of use to you:

[Can ABNewPersonViewController be used to edit existing records?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5988151/can-abnewpersonviewcontroller-be-used-to-edit-existing-records)

It covers a tutorial with your exact problem.

Comment: Thanks, but that's what I've already found. The problem is in apples doc they are just creating new RecordRefs and do not chose an existing one to edit. Further the problem that the ABUnknownPersonViewController does not show the same properties like the ABNewPersonViewController is still present

Comment: @Alexander: I am also facing same problem.Can you tell me what you did to overcome this?

Answer (score 1):

Though this thread is old, it might help others. Try to override the cancel event as shown here. It worked for me.

```
- (void)showNewPersonViewController:(ABRecordRef)person
{
    //show new Person view controller
    ABNewPersonViewController *vcNewPerson = [[ABNewPersonViewController alloc] init];
    vcNewPerson.newPersonViewDelegate = self;
    vcNewPerson.displayedPerson = person;

    vcNewPerson.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem  = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(onNewPersonCancelClick)];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vcNewPerson animated:YES];

    [vcNewPerson release];
}

- (void)onNewPersonCancelClick
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```